# function in if statement got undefined in first time only but in rest time the function call as well

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

I'm trying to check the file extension before using ng-upload, but during the normal condition that checks if the file is error free, I'm trying to add my function.
Something very strange happens. First time I tried to upload, I received this error:

> ReferenceError: extension_check is not defined
>       at application-9d9dfe26d056c7fe9da969ebdf1e1f7f.js:76141
>       at Object.forEach (application-9d9dfe26d056c7fe9da969ebdf1e1f7f.js:26353)
>       at Scope.$scope.uploadFiles (application-9d9dfe26d056c7fe9da969ebdf1e1f7f.js:76140)
>       at $parseFunctionCall (application-9d9dfe26d056c7fe9da969ebdf1e1f7f.js:38330)
>       at update (application-9d9dfe26d056c7fe9da969ebdf1e1f7f.js:73683)
>       at application-9d9dfe26d056c7fe9da969ebdf1e1f7f.js:73695
>       at application-9d9dfe26d056c7fe9da969ebdf1e1f7f.js:42205
>       at completeOutstandingRequest (application-9d9dfe26d056c7fe9da969ebdf1e1f7f.js:30920)
>       at application-9d9dfe26d056c7fe9da969ebdf1e1f7f.js:31300

but in all other times the function calls as well

Code:

```
$scope.uploadFiles = function(files) {
    $scope.files = files;


    angular.forEach(files, function(file) {
        if (file && !file.$error && extension_check(file.name)) {
            file.upload = Upload.upload({
              url: 'http://172.18.139.3:3000/attachments',
              file: file

            });

            file.upload.then(function (response) {
              $timeout(function () {
                file.result = response.data;
                if (file.result.header.status["code"] == "ERROR") {

                    file.$error = true
                    $scope.message = file.result.header.status.message
                    console.log('file ' + file.name + ' is got error . Message: ' + file.result.header.status.message);
                }

              });
            }, function (response) {
              if (response.status > 0)
                $scope.status.message = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
                // $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            });

            file.upload.progress(function (evt) {
              file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * 
                                       evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        } 


        console.log(file)  
    });

    extension_check = function(name) {

        extension_allow = ['jpg','jpeg','bmp','png'];
        ext = name.substr(name.lastIndexOf('.')+1).toLowerCase();
        console.log (ext);
        flag = (extension_allow.indexOf(ext) > -1);
        console.log (flag);
        return flag;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because first time when the for loop is executed the variable `extension_check` is not defined. The second time since you have `extension_check` as a global variable it will have the function reference.

One solution is to move the declaration of `extension_check` above the loop, another is to make use of function hoisting by using function declaration syntax

```
$scope.uploadFiles = function (files) {
    $scope.files = files;


    angular.forEach(files, function (file) {
        if (file && !file.$error && extension_check(file.name)) {
            file.upload = Upload.upload({
                url: 'http://172.18.139.3:3000/attachments',
                file: file

            });

            file.upload.then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    file.result = response.data;
                    if (file.result.header.status["code"] == "ERROR") {

                        file.$error = true
                        $scope.message = file.result.header.status.message
                        console.log('file ' + file.name + ' is got error . Message: ' + file.result.header.status.message);
                    }

                });
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0) $scope.status.message = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
                // $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            });

            file.upload.progress(function (evt) {
                file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        }


        console.log(file)
    });

    function extension_check(name) {

        var extension_allow = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'bmp', 'png'];
        var ext = name.substr(name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
        console.log(ext);
        var flag = (extension_allow.indexOf(ext) > -1);
        console.log(flag);
        return flag;

    }
}
```

---

You can also define the function outside of `uploadFiles` since it doesn't depend on any closure variables

```
var extension_check = function extension_check(name) {
    var extension_allow = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'bmp', 'png'];
    var ext = name.substr(name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
    console.log(ext);
    var flag = (extension_allow.indexOf(ext) > -1);
    console.log(flag);
    return flag;

}

$scope.uploadFiles = function (files) {
    $scope.files = files;

    angular.forEach(files, function (file) {
        if (file && !file.$error && extension_check(file.name)) {
            file.upload = Upload.upload({
                url: 'http://172.18.139.3:3000/attachments',
                file: file

            });

            file.upload.then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    file.result = response.data;
                    if (file.result.header.status["code"] == "ERROR") {

                        file.$error = true
                        $scope.message = file.result.header.status.message
                        console.log('file ' + file.name + ' is got error . Message: ' + file.result.header.status.message);
                    }

                });
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0) $scope.status.message = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
                // $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            });

            file.upload.progress(function (evt) {
                file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        }


        console.log(file)
    });
}
```

Also note to make the variable as a local variable

Comment: thanks, the last solution works fine, just not understand why call to function not made the reference to.